# how can i store song from ipod to document directory of my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i can be able to fetch the ipod library and also able to play that file on one page but can not be able to store the path of selected song and play it to another page. so can any one tell me how  can i copy the selected song to document directory of my application and can use it to another location
thanks

Comment: I dont think you can do that. Besides copying a song will take up quite a bit of space.

Comment: ok no problem. but i will find it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you have the song in your ipod and want to extract the music out, you'll need some special software to do this.

try http://www.itransferstudio.com/ it's a free download